# Python web scraping and data mining

Tags: python, web-scraping, text-mining, data-extraction

i am doing web scraping on a wikipedia page. the code seems to be right, but i have a problem at the 11th line of the code.

code:

```
A=[]
B=[]
C=[]
D=[]
E=[]
F=[]
for row in film.findAll('tr'):
    states=row.findAll('th')
    cells=row.findAll('td')
    if len(cells==9):
        A.append(states[0].find(text=True))
        B.append(cells[0].find(text=True))
        C.append(cells[1].find(text=True))
        D.append(cells[2].find(text=True))
        E.append(cells[3].find(text=True))
        F.append(cells[4].find(text=True))
```

error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-38-bc871627aa75> in <module>()
      8     states=row.findAll('th')
      9     cells=row.findAll('td')
---> 10     if len(cells==9):
     11         A.append(states[0].find(text=True))
     12         B.append(cells[0].find(text=True))

TypeError: object of type 'bool' has no len()
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps?

```
if(len(cells) == 9):
    whatever_code
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the variable cells inside the brackets of the len() method. Since you have cells==9 inside the brackets the if statement is trying to find the length of a variable named 'cells==9' with no arguments.

It should look like this

```
if len(cells) == 9:
```